# Not all Information is appearing in Kibana (Serilog)

Tags: serilog

When I run my AspNetCore V5 app I only see logging appear in Kibana up to the point I call `CreateHostBuilder(args)`.

So, in Kibana I see

> Step 1

and

> Starting app

But nothing after that. Even if I add `Log.Information("Requested data");` in a controller method that is being executed, I don't see it.

## appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

## Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BlazorElkSerilogTest.Server
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //configure logging first
            ConfigureLogging();

            Log.Information("Step {step}", 1);
            IHostBuilder hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args);
            Log.Information("Step {step}", 2);
            IHost host = hostBuilder.Build();
            Log.Information("Step {step}", 3);
            host.Run();
        }

        static void ConfigureLogging()
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile(
                    $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                    optional: true)
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(ConfigureElasticSink(configuration, environment))
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", environment)
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        static ElasticsearchSinkOptions ConfigureElasticSink(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string environment)
        {
            return new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
            {
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                IndexFormat = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{environment?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}"
            };
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting app");
                return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                            {
                                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                            })
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
                    {
                        configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                        configuration.AddJsonFile(
                            $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json",
                            optional: true);
                    })
                    .UseSerilog();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Fatal(e, "Application startup failed");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try/catch/finally should wrap the code in `Main`, not `CreateHostBuilder` - otherwise the logger is closed before the app runs!